# Lauch a background process in Ruby and regist the PID

Tags: ruby, pid

What is the best way to launch multiple process in background with ruby ? I need to use `Thread.new` ?

I have like 5 process to launch in background then i want to get the pid to stop properly all the process.In bash i can do it easyli:

```
htop &
echo $! >/tmp/htop.pid
```

And to kill:

```
kill `cat /tmp/htop.pid`
```

I want to be able to do the same thing with Ruby

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`spawn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn):

```
pid = spawn('htop')
```

And to [`Process.kill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process.html#method-c-kill):

```
Process.kill('TERM', pid)
```